# Drupal 8 How to create ajax_deliver route callback?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

In d7 menu_callback we had type where we could set type as ajax_deliver. Ajax_deliver type in Drupal 7 avoids whole Drupal bootstrap and makes the lightweight callback and directly calls functionality defined in function.

I want to avoid Drupal 8 bootstrap to load and want a lightweight callback which directly call my function. Is there a way in D8??